# Навешивание события на несуществующие элементы.

Tags: javascript, php

Сранно тема звучит ,но не знал как назвать корректно тему.
В зависимости от условий на главной странице идет показ либо 1 блока элементов либо 2.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])):
?>
<p>Привет</p>

 <?
   else:
?>
<form action="1.php" method="post">
<?
   endif;
?>
```

У меня есть обработчики ,которые я навешиваю по событию window.onload на элементы ,которые генерируются в каждом условии.
Получается так ,что в 1 случае ошибка принавешивании обработчика ,которого не существует,поскольку цикл <? else:?>  не сработал,и наоборот.Как лучше поступить?

Comment: Проверяйте, существует ли объект, прежде, чем работать с ним.

Comment: Вариант,спс.

Comment: Спасибо Вам.Преобразуйте в ответ.Закрою...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без `jQuery` - [подсмотрите](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L724) как сделан `$.on()` в `jQuery` и сделайте так-же. С `jQuery`  - используйте `$.on()`